# magickimage.net (C#) image saturation when converting format?

Tags: c#, imagemagick

I tried to use magickimage.net (C#) to convert HEIC image files (from iPhone 7) to JPG format.

Using all the default values (see below), though it converts successfully -- however, when comparing the converted image, vs, if I copy the files from iPhone directly to my computer as JPG, I noticed the images converted from magickimage look more "pale", lacking vivid color (saturation, I would say).

Just wondering if anyone happens to know the right settings to improve that?

```
using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage(files[i]))
{
    image.Format = MagickFormat.Jpeg;
    image.Write(MyFile.ReplaceFileExtension(files[i], "jpg"));
}
```

Comment: Just a thought. I am not an expert on the iPhone. The phone may be doing some auto-correction when converting (HEIC->JPG) using internal settings it captures about the environment when it takes the image. Those might not be kept with the heic image when transferred out of the phone?

Comment: Yeah, I was also thinking about it, but not sure how to use magickimage (in #c) to make the same changes..

Comment: I do not think you can at least not easily. You would have to know the settings from the iPhone and then know how the iPhone processes the image. Then you would have to figure out how to achieve all that in ImageMagick. It is not easy to reverse engineer when you do not know the algorithms used. But then I am not an iPhone expert.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, most likely not apply the correct color profile.

Check the image if it has Color properties ie. Table VII. Image Properties and Figure 1 in the Technical spec for HEIF is at:
https://nokiatech.github.io/heif/technical.html

Also I would check if the following display the image correctly.
https://github.com/liuziangexit/HEIF-Utility/tree/master/HEIF%20Utility%20English